# Sort a nested list by the length of the respective sublists

Tags: r, list

How can I sort a nested list by the length of the sublists:

```
l <- list(list("a","b","c"), list("d","e"), list("f"))
```

using this it should give back:

```
list(list("f"), list("d","e"), list("a","b","c"))
```

Comment: `l[order(vapply(l, length, 1L))]` ? (feel free to add it as an answer, if this is what you're looking for).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have used

```
l[order(sapply(l, length))]
```

The solution given in the comment of @Arun

```
l[order(vapply(l, length, 1L))]
```

may give some performance advantage by telling R that everything returned by the length function will be an integer: "For vapply, you basically give R an example of what sort of thing your function will return, which can save some time coercing returned values to fit in a single atomic vector."  See:

[R Grouping functions: sapply vs. lapply vs. apply. vs. tapply vs. by vs. aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega)