# Sort sub graph list in igraph by number of edges R

Tags: r, list, sorting, igraph

I have an igraph sub-graph cluster list as follows:

```
head(modules,2)
[[1]]
IGRAPH UN-- 4 3 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), value (e/n), sourceID (e/n), targetID (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 538--516 539--516 539--517

[[2]]
IGRAPH UN-- 5 6 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), value (e/n), sourceID (e/n), targetID (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 293--274 293--291 293--290 293--275 274--290 274--275
```

I want to sort tis subgraph list `modules` by the number of edges in each subgraph, (or based on the length of the sublists within it).

From the answer to this question: [Sort a nested list by the length of the respective sublists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716595/sort-a-nested-list-by-the-length-of-the-respective-sublists)

I tried:

```
out <- modules[order(sapply(modules,length),decreasing=T)]
```

But this just gave back the same list:

```
head(out, 2)

[[1]]
IGRAPH UN-- 4 3 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), value (e/n), sourceID (e/n), targetID (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 538--516 539--516 539--517

[[2]]
IGRAPH UN-- 5 6 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), value (e/n), sourceID (e/n), targetID (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 293--274 293--291 293--290 293--275 274--290 274--275
```

This is because the sublists can only be accessed by using `[[]]` notation ([The difference between [] and [[]] notations for accessing the elements of a list or dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-and-notations-for-accessing-the-elements-of-a-lis)).

The lengths of the sublists when evaluated using `[]` all equal 1, whereas the lengths of the sublists when evaluated using `[[]]` give the true length:

```
length(modules[[1]])
[1] 10
> length(modules[1])
[1] 1
```

How can I modify the above to use the `[[]]` length rather than the `[]` length?

---

Updated to include full list and output:

```
modules
>
[[1]]
IGRAPH UN-- 4 3 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), value (e/n), sourceID (e/n), targetID (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 538--516 539--516 539--517

[[2]]
IGRAPH UN-- 5 6 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), value (e/n), sourceID (e/n), targetID (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 293--274 293--291 293--290 293--275 274--290 274--275

[[3]]
IGRAPH UN-- 6 7 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), value (e/n), sourceID (e/n), targetID (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 700--654 700--655 700--649 654--649 654--699 655--699 655--701

[[4]]
IGRAPH UN-- 4 3 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), value (e/n), sourceID (e/n), targetID (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 575--578 574--580 578--580

[[5]]
IGRAPH UN-- 4 4 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), value (e/n), sourceID (e/n), targetID (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 703--739 703--740 704--739 704--740
```

Sorted output:
    out
    >
    [[1]]
    IGRAPH UN-- 4 3 -- 
    + attr: name (v/c), value (e/n), sourceID (e/n), targetID (e/n)
    + edges (vertex names):
    [1] 538--516 539--516 539--517

```
[[2]]
IGRAPH UN-- 5 6 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), value (e/n), sourceID (e/n), targetID (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 293--274 293--291 293--290 293--275 274--290 274--275

[[3]]
IGRAPH UN-- 6 7 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), value (e/n), sourceID (e/n), targetID (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 700--654 700--655 700--649 654--649 654--699 655--699 655--701

[[4]]
IGRAPH UN-- 4 3 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), value (e/n), sourceID (e/n), targetID (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 575--578 574--580 578--580

[[5]]
IGRAPH UN-- 4 4 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), value (e/n), sourceID (e/n), targetID (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 703--739 703--740 704--739 704--740
```

dput modules:

```
dput(modules)
list(structure(list(4, FALSE, c(2, 2, 3), c(0, 1, 1), c(0, 1, 
2), c(0, 1, 2), c(0, 0, 0, 2, 3), c(0, 1, 3, 3, 3), list(c(1, 
0, 1, 1), structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), structure(list(
    name = c("538", "539", "516", "517")), .Names = "name"), 
    structure(list(value = c(0.7186, 0.7186, 0.7186), sourceID = c(2610235, 
    2610236, 2610236), targetID = c(2578681, 2578681, 2578682
    )), .Names = c("value", "sourceID", "targetID"))), <environment>), class = "igraph"), 
    structure(list(5, FALSE, c(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4), c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 1), c(0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5), c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), c(0, 
    0, 1, 2, 4, 6), c(0, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6), list(c(1, 0, 1, 3), 
        structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), structure(list(
            name = c("293", "274", "291", "290", "275")), .Names = "name"), 
        structure(list(value = c(0.7286, 0.8785, 0.8785, 0.7286, 
        0.7286, 0.7786), sourceID = c(1442372, 1475074, 1475074, 
        1475074, 1442372, 1442372), targetID = c(1475074, 1467171, 
        1466635, 1448436, 1466635, 1448436)), .Names = c("value", 
        "sourceID", "targetID"))), <environment>), class = "igraph"), 
    structure(list(6, FALSE, c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5), c(0, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 2, 2), c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
    5, 6), c(0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7), c(0, 3, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7), list(
        c(1, 0, 1, 5), structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), 
        structure(list(name = c("700", "654", "655", "649", "699", 
        "701")), .Names = "name"), structure(list(value = c(0.7078, 
        0.7078, 0.7078, 0.7744, 0.7078, 0.7078, 0.7078), sourceID = c(3062163, 
        3062164, 3090708, 3062163, 3062163, 3062164, 3062164), 
            targetID = c(3090708, 3090708, 3058341, 3058341, 
            3090707, 3090707, 3090709)), .Names = c("value", 
        "sourceID", "targetID"))), <environment>), class = "igraph"), 
    structure(list(4, FALSE, c(2, 3, 3), c(0, 1, 2), c(0, 1, 
    2), c(0, 1, 2), c(0, 0, 0, 1, 3), c(0, 1, 2, 3, 3), list(
        c(1, 0, 1, 7), structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), 
        structure(list(name = c("575", "574", "578", "580")), .Names = "name"), 
        structure(list(value = c(0.7744, 0.7744, 0.7744), sourceID = c(2821538, 
        2821537, 2822504), targetID = c(2822504, 2824052, 2824052
        )), .Names = c("value", "sourceID", "targetID"))), <environment>), class = "igraph"), 
    structure(list(4, FALSE, c(2, 3, 2, 3), c(0, 0, 1, 1), c(0, 
    2, 1, 3), c(0, 1, 2, 3), c(0, 0, 0, 2, 4), c(0, 2, 4, 4, 
    4), list(c(1, 0, 1, 9), structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), 
        structure(list(name = c("703", "704", "739", "740")), .Names = "name"), 
        structure(list(value = c(0.7744, 0.7744, 0.7744, 0.7744
        ), sourceID = c(3094741, 3094741, 3094742, 3094742), 
            targetID = c(3111079, 3111080, 3111079, 3111080)), .Names = c("value", 
        "sourceID", "targetID"))), <environment>), class = "igraph"))
```

Comment: `out <- modules[order(sapply(modules,function(x) length(x[[1]])),decreasing=T)]`

Comment: @AndrewGustar Same result :(

Comment: If I do `modules <- list(a=list(c(1,2,3)),b=list(c(4,5,6,7)))` then 
`modules[order(sapply(modules,function(x) length(x[[1]])),decreasing=T)]` gives me `$b` before `$a`.  Your structure must be different - can you post the output of `dput(modules[1:2])`?

Comment: @AndrewGustar Please see my update, added to answer. It's not pretty :(

Comment: I see what you mean!  Try it with `function(x) length(x[[9]][[3]]$name)`.

Comment: `out <- modules[order(sapply(modules,function(x) length(x[[9]][[3]]$name)))]` gives `Error in .Call("R_igraph_adjacent_vertices", graph, vv, mode, PACKAGE = "igraph") : At iterators.c:759 : Cannot create iterator, invalid vertex id, Invalid vertex id`  I'm not sure why it doesn't work. You may have seen that I found a solution in which case, I'm really sorry to waste your time :( I really really appreciate that you tried to help.

Comment: No problem - I think the other solution is much more sensible!

Comment: @AndrewGustar Ah great - Thank you very much again! Have  a nice day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having trawled through the `igraph` documentation it turns out you can use `ecount` to return the edge count for a particular sub-graph cluster.

As such, doing:

```
out <- modules[order(sapply(modules, ecount))]
```

gives the expected output:

```
out
[[1]]
IGRAPH UN-- 4 3 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), value (e/n), sourceID (e/n), targetID (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 538--516 539--516 539--517

[[2]]
IGRAPH UN-- 4 3 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), value (e/n), sourceID (e/n), targetID (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 575--578 574--580 578--580

[[3]]
IGRAPH UN-- 4 4 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), value (e/n), sourceID (e/n), targetID (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 703--739 703--740 704--739 704--740

[[4]]
IGRAPH UN-- 5 6 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), value (e/n), sourceID (e/n), targetID (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 293--274 293--291 293--290 293--275 274--290 274--275

[[5]]
IGRAPH UN-- 6 7 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), value (e/n), sourceID (e/n), targetID (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 700--654 700--655 700--649 654--649 654--699 655--699 655--701
```

Documentation at:

http://igraph.org/r/doc/sub-sub-.igraph.html

http://igraph.org/r/doc/gsize.html